# Is it a good pattern to use Azure service bus as backup messaging service?

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

We are considering of a design pattern where

1. Web service tries to insert data into database
2. If that call fails and db is not available
3. then we pass that data into azure service bus
4. Once the db is back up, some other service will read data from service bus and insert into database.

I personally have not seen this pattern however is there any issue with this design ?

Comment: Hi, we inherited a similar pattern once but it used a normal storage queue as ordering wasn't important and all DB submissions went through the Q, we converted to EF in the end as the Q system was too problematic. I think trying to combine the 2 would also be problematic unless you have strict control over the order in which things are processed and how the service would recover when the DB is available again. You also have to consider if it's a client facing application how do you handle showing the user the most up to date data. Without more info on the larger setup it's hard to advise.

Answer (score 1):

The way queuing system are usually used is slightly different from what you're asking.
Queues allow reliable command execution if the destination resource is not available (database) and balance the load on the resource rather than overwhelming it.

The steps would be:

1. Web service sends a Service Bus message with the data that needs to be inserted into the database.
2. A backend service is peeking the messages and tries to insert into the database.
3. If the operation is failing or the database is not available, the message is retried.